# How to connect a web service to an Oracle database

Tags: ios, database, oracle

I'm trying to connect an iOS application to an Oracle DB through the Rest web service. The question I have is how can I connect the web service to the Database in order to retrieve data from it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to use the web services provide by the your php developers team they develop the response in XML or JSON format which you access in your app by using NSXML parser or JSON parsing.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/overview/index.html

Comment: Thanks both, but Rohit if I had a PHP developers team then I sure wouldn't be here to ask, what do you think?

Comment: @Rene i saw this link, but how can I use this Oracle product?